# How do I have an FTP "folder" recognized in windows 7 visible by intelij (php storm 8)?

Tags: windows-7, ftp, intellij-idea, phpstorm

It took me a few days to get an FTP "folder" able to work in something other than filezilla, and it finally came together now I need to get it to work so I don't need to drag folders over. What steps do I need to take to make my internet folder accessible by intellij PHPStorm, since it's not getting recognized by the browse option?

The reason why I gave up on their FTP settings is because it has access, but can't connect the FTP.

Comment: The FTP folders in Windows Explorer (and WebDAV, for that matter) are not real folders, and are only available in Windows Explorer/Internet Explorer I believe.

Comment: how do I set the "folder" up for FTPing then?  I already knew it was a shortcut folder.

Comment: You might look here for that: http://serverfault.com/questions/6079/how-can-i-mount-an-ftp-to-a-drive-letter-in-windows

Comment: @DarthAndroid that worked brilliantly, you should write that answer down so I can give you some points.

Answer (score 1):

The FTP and WebDAV folders you can create in Windows Explorer and Internet Explorer will not show up outside of those programs. To mount a FTP share where any program can access it, you need a program which will mount the FTP share as a *drive* in Windows.

This answer has a number of recommendations:

https://serverfault.com/questions/6079/how-can-i-mount-an-ftp-to-a-drive-letter-in-windows

Comment: That only worked for the 20 day free trial, how do I make one permanent?

Comment: @acoder Buy a license to the software.

Comment: When I get the money